# How to get the source file name after consolidating multiple excel files into a single file?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a single file by consolidating 4 excel files into 1.
here is the code for the same

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim row As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim currow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(65536, 2).End(xlUp).row
Columns("O:O").Insert
Range("O1").Value = "Source"
For i = 1 To 4 Step 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O2:O" & LastRow).Value = "Dump" & i
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\BV\Desktop\Excel" & "\Dump" & i & ".xlsx")
With wb.Sheets("Data")
    If i = 1 Then
     row = 1
    Else
     row = 2
    End If
Do Until .Range("A" & row).Value = vbNullString
currow = currow + 1

For n = 0 To 13 Step 1
Me.Range("A" & currow).Offset(columnoffset:=n).Value = .Range("A" & row).Offset(columnoffset:=n).Value
Next n
row = row + 1
Loop
End With
wb.Close True
Next i
Fees_check
Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Dump1,Dump2,Dump3 and Dump4 are the source file names.
I want to add another column which gives the source file name after consolidating like Dump1,Dump2 etc.
Right now im getting the value as Dump4 for all the rows.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are constantly overwriting here `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O2:O" & LastRow).Value = "Dump" & i`. Btw `row` is not a good variable name imv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O2:O" & LastRow).Value = "Dump" & i
```

Every time you go through the loop you just replace values from "O2" to the last row with `dump & i` which, on the final time, just fills the whole column with "dump4"

So, get rid of that line and use your `CurrRow` variable to populate column "O" instead, maybe by just inserting a line in the bit that actually moves across the data, like this:

```
For n = 0 To 13 Step 1
Me.Range("A" & currow).Offset(columnoffset:=n).Value = .Range("A" & row).Offset(columnoffset:=n).Value
Me.Range("O" & currow).Value2 = "Dump" & i ' INSERT THIS LINE
Next n
```

This is a quick fix, I'd normally fill a range in one go but I think you're just dealing with small amounts of data it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks fren. Appreciate your help.